# github: Not sure what it means to add @personname on the body of the issue

Tags: github

Someone asked me to do this: create an issue on your repository and add our Github handles to the issue body (@name1 and @name2) so we can review your submission.

I used the github software on windows7 and uploaded my source, then went to github.com and created an issue, and then added the above to what I believe is the "issue body."

I believe I've done it correctly, but given github's wierd lingual and it's unintuitive use, I have some doubts.  I even had issue signing up an account with them as it gave no errors what was wrong.  needless to say, github has been really irritating.

Please see this image and let me know if this is done correctly:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxTAvARlh78dbXJGckRzS01oNVk/edit?usp=sharing

Thank you.

Comment: You've blocked out most of what we need to see if it's correct (i.e. syntax and highlighting of the @mention)

Comment: Erm, it's just a mention, the same as on Twitter or Facebook. The person you tag gets notified.

Answer (score 0):

See @mentions on Github (which I believe is what you want):

- https://github.com/blog/957-introducing-issue-mentions
- https://github.com/blog/821